# How to print many times in one line, with many rows?

Tags: python

I know how to print in loop in one line:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in array:
   print("This is {}".format(i), end="")
   time.sleep(1)
```

But if i want one output with many rows (with line breaks \n), how i can do something like this:

```
print("This is {} \n And this is two {}".format(i, i + 1), end="")
time.sleep(1)
```

The output will be:

```
This is 1 
And this is two 2This is 2 
And this is two 3This is 3 
....
```

And i want:

```
This is 1            #increment here in one line to 2, 3, 4..
And this is two 2    #same here 3, 4, 5..
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You need to use `curses` to move around on the screen.

Comment: Why the `php` tag? it looks `python` code to me.

Comment: I changed to python, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
import time
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(len(array)):
    if (i != len(array) - 1):
        print("This is {}".format(array[i]), end="\nAnd ")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("This is {}".format(array[i]))
```

output:

```
This is 1
And This is 2
And This is 3
And This is 4
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the point. I need to have output still in one line. I want to use it to print graphs that shows changing values per secound

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by one line. Can you give any example outputs? apart from the one you currently have given